# Octave one line two plot differ from multiple line plot

Tags: plot, octave

I'm fitting some data, but when I plot the data and fit in one-line-plot (see left figure) the drawn graph is correct

```
plot(x, y, '.b;data;', [0.05 2], phi(1)+phi(2)*[0.05 2], '--r;fit;', [0.05 2]);
```

But when I used two separated plot (see right figure) the graph differs from mention above

```
hold on;

plot(x, y, '.b;data;', [0.05 2]);
plot(phi(1)+phi(2)*[0.05 2], '--r;fit;', [0.05 2]);

hold off;
grid on;
```

Data

```
[x, y]
ans =
    0.050000     3571.000000
    0.100000     6567.000000
    0.200000    12760.000000
    0.300000    20512.000000
    0.400000    25480.000000
    0.500000    32088.000000
    1.000000    63223.000000
    2.000000   128690.000000
```

Calculate Linear Regression

```
A = [N, sum(x); sum(x), sum(x.*x)];
b = [sum(y); sum(x.*y)];
phi = inv(A)*b;
```

Is there any way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Minor issue:  you should not use  `phi = inv(A)*b` but  `phi = A\b;` . It makes no difference here but it can make difference on larger or bad conditioned matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the x-axis values are not specified then `1:numel(y)` are considered to be the x-axis values.

In your code:

```
%Your first graph:
plot(x, y, '.b;data;', [0.05 2], phi(1)+phi(2)*[0.05 2], '--r;fit;', [0.05 2]);
                                                                     %^^^^^^^

%Your second graph:

plot(x, y, '.b;data;', [0.05 2]);
                      %^^^^^^^^^

plot(phi(1)+phi(2)*[0.05 2], '--r;fit;', [0.05 2]);
    %!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!             %^^^^^^^^^
```

The parts highlighted with `^` in above `plot` commands have `x=[1 2]` and `y=[0.05 2]` and the part highlighted with `!` has `x=[1 2]` and `y=phi(1)+phi(2)*[0.05 2]`. You can see those lines being drawn if you zoom at that area.

So your first plot command should be:

```
plot(x, y, '.b;data;', [0.05 2], phi(1)+phi(2)*[0.05 2], '--r;fit;');
```

and it should be split like this:

```
plot(x, y, '.b;data;'); 
hold on;
plot([0.05 2], phi(1)+phi(2)*[0.05 2], '--r;fit;');
```